# HTML cannot read inline

Tags: html, css, css-float

I need some assistance. it keeps displaying the elements [(SEE THE LAYOUT)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RbUmb.png) as block with a margin that stretches full even though the margins are 0.

*HTML:*

```
<div class="flex cols-2">
    <div style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background:blue;"></div>
    <p>hello</p>
    <div style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background:gold;"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/*----FLEX----*/
.flex {
  display: inline;
}

.cols-2 {
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-basis: 49%;
}

/*----FLOAT----*/

div {
  float: left;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with PHP and SQL?

Comment: First of all, this has absolutely nothing to do with PHP. So please title & tag appropriately next time.

Comment: Second - how do you actually _want_ this to display? The class names suggest you want to use the flexbox layout model here - but with `display: inline`, you make the whole thing _not_ flex, and therefor any other flex properties don’t have an effect any more either. Are you perhaps looking for `display: inline-flex` (to create a flex element that does not take full width, but only as much as needed by the content)?

Comment: All in all, I think instead of asking here, you should rather be working through a couple of beginner tutorials on the matter right now (we are not here to _teach_ basics). https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ should get you started pretty good.

Comment: hello, it's acutally labelled PHP because it is a php file running through a wamp server. if i just view it within an HTML file then i don't get this problem. I am fully competant with the use of all html and css properties and i changed the `display: flex;` property to `display:inline;` as a hopeful but useless answer to my problems.

Comment: It's almost as if the PHP doesn't read the code the same. It did the same for me with a grid that has 1 row 2 cols, but displayed all the elements in one row. So I'm actually not to sure where the problem comes in. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons I detest Bootstrap is that it requires people to learn a lot of custom class names instead of CSS. It hides the CSS from you.

Bootstrap is setting `display: flex` on the element, but then you are changing it to `display: inline` so it isn't using flexbox any more.

Set it to `display: inline-flex` for an inline flexbox element.

```css
.flex {
  display: inline-flex;
}

.cols-2 {
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-basis: 49%;
}
```

```html
<p>With inline-flex</p>

<div class="flex cols-2">
  <div style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background:blue;"></div>
  <p>hello</p>
  <div style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background:gold;"></div>
</div>

<hr>

<p>Without flex</p>

<div class="cols-2">
  <div style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background:blue;"></div>
  <p>hello</p>
  <div style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background:gold;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am not using bootstrap because I have also had to many problems with CSS frameworks. But I already tried to set `dispaly:inline-flex;` but nothing happened.

Comment: I have also tried setting `htm`l to `inline-block` as well as `float:left` and nothing. your help is much appreciated!

Comment: I've edited a live demo into the answer. `inline-flex` clearly has an effect.

Comment: it is in php file though being run though on a WAMP server and I believe this is where the problem comes in, if only i knew what it was. If I view just my code in a browser as html then it works fine too. I have literally copy-pasted the cose to make sure i dont miss anything and nothing changes

Comment: HTML and CSS are HTML and CSS. It doesn't matter *how* you generate it.

Comment: Ok, well in that case my problem must be lying somewhere with wamp because this code is still in a row :'(. It does the same thing when I try to use a grid with 1row 2cols (just the 'boxes' not the text) so it must be something overwriting it all

Comment: I believe I found the solution. PHP writes only inline but if there is HTML code in a PHP file no matter what you do the elements cannot display inline they will display block. So you will have to use the PHP `echo` function to write elements inline.

Comment: No. That isn't how PHP works. It just outputs text.